# Why I can't do this (error C2275: 'A' : illegal use of this type as an expression)

Tags: c++, class

Why I can't do this?
compiler says

> warning C4832: token '.' is illegal
>   after UDT 'A : see declaration of 'A'
>   error C2275: 'A' : illegal use of this
>   type as an expression : see
>   declaration of 'A'

```
class A{
public:
    std::string getString(){return "olalal";}
};

class B{
public:
    std::string getStringFromA() {return A.getString();}
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    cout << b.getStringFromA();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getString` is not a static function. You have to call it on an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only call non-`static` member functions on an object.

E.g.

```
std::string B::getStringFromA()
{
    A object_of_type_A;
    return object_of_type_A.getString();
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a unnamed temporary `A` and call `getString()` on that, E.g.

```
class B {
public:
    std::string getStringFromA() { return A().getString(); }
};
```

If `getString()` were declared `static` in `A`, you could call the function without an object, but the syntax uses `::`, not `.`.

E.g.

```
std::string B::getStringFromA()
{
    return A::getString();
}
```

With a function name like `getStringFromA`, though, I would expect to pass a parameter of the particular `A` that I wanted to get the string from, perhaps passing the `A` by reference.

```
class B {
public:
    std::string getStringFromA(A& a) { return a.getString(); }
};
```

If `getString` in `A` doesn't actually modify the `A` object it would be better to declare the function `const` so that it can be called on `const` instances of `A`. In this case, a `const` reference could be used.

```
class A {
public:
    std::string getString() const { return "olalal"; }
};

class B {
public:
    std::string getStringFromA(const A& a) { return a.getString(); }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`getString()` is not a *static* member function; you must call it on a specific instance of `A`, e.g. `A a; a.getString();`.

Comment: ..beat me by seconds.. need stronger coffee... I'll remove my answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `A::getString()` isn't a static method you need to call it on an *instance* of `A`.